# Black holes: Is merger inevitable when horizons touch?

Tags: black-holes, simulations, event-horizon, binary-stars

I watched a simulation of the binary black hole merger of 2019 April 12 
https://www.ligo.caltech.edu/video/ligo20200420v1

When the "apparent horizons" (their terminology; are those different from event horizons?) touched, the two combined and the merger was complete. So I'm wondering: would it be possible for two black holes to quickly pass by each other, so that their horizons briefly touched, but then they continued on their ways separately.

PS: The video was nice, but I would have preferred it stay on a 2D plane. I don't know if the changing points of view was done by the animators, or if the two objects really did move around in three dimensions.

Comment: What do you mean by "touched"? The event horizon is not a physical place but a mathematical boundary.

Comment: Here is a much better video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?app=desktop&v=Y1M-AbWIlVQ

Comment: Once two horizons touch, it is already a single black hole.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you mean by "touch" since the event horizon is not a physical location$^1$.

If you mean *overlap*, and if you are asking if it's possible that merging can be avoided even if the event horizons of both black holes were to overlap, then the answer is still *no*. They will merge (regardless of how fast the black holes are moving).
The escape velocity at an event horizon is equal to the speed of light, and nothing (with mass$^2$) can have this speed, so even if two black holes approach with a great speed, they will merge if their event horizons overlap.

---

$^1$ The event horizon is a mathematical boundary, where for example, in a Schwarzschild black hole, the event horizon is defined by the Schwarzschild radius $$r_S=\frac{2GM}{c^2}$$ where $r_s$ describes a *mathematical sphere* (meaning non-physical) surrounding the gravitating mass $M$.

$^2$ Even something massless, like light, still will not be able to escape since the future of all events (within the EH) lie within the event horizon.

Answer (score 2):

Event horizons are defined as [trapped surfaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trapped_surface), closed and orientable surfaces that act as one-way boundaries. The apparent horizon is the union of all trapped surfaces, essentially building up a 4-dimensional boundary in spacetime no particle can get out of. Note that they are not physical things, and can move about faster than light. The [topology censorship theorem](https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/9305017) implies that they cannot have holes like doughnuts.

The second law of [black hole thermodynamics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_hole_thermodynamics) gives a very strong reason to think the horizon area cannot decrease, which it would do if a $2M$ mass hole (area $4M^2$) could turn into two mass $M$ holes (total area $2M^2$). There is [a somewhat devious possibility of mergers followed by splitting into three or more holes](https://www.science20.com/hammock_physicist/how_split_black_holes-98465) that obeys this, but [considering the entropy carefully this is disfavoured](https://www.science20.com/hammock_physicist/splitting_black_holes_take_2-99159).

What I have not seen is a purely classical argument for the non-separation of a black hole merger. One can obviously take the time reversed spacetime manifold of a merger and get a valid manifold that splits - but this is a black hole disturbed by a complex ingoing set of strong gravitational waves that splits, a bit like how a loud crash sound converging on some shards can in principle make them reassemble into a vase jumping back up on a shelf. Possible, but thermodynamically impossible.

But I have a feeling there should be topological arguments about the trapped surfaces that could also be used.